# How to efficiently find multiple items by their _ids in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Suppose I have a MongoDB database with two collections — 'fruits' and 'baskets'. Each fruit has a lot of information to it besides the name, such as calories, country of origin and whatnot.

A basket is basically just a group of fruits, namely, besides the properties of the basket, each basket item has a field `FRUIT_ARRAY` which holds the `_id`'s of the fruits. For the simplicity, suppose each fruit can only belong to one basket.

Now somebody gives me a basket `_id` and I need to extract the corresponding fruit records as efficient as possible with all their details. My question is - is there a more efficient way than just doing this (I am using a python wrapper for interaction with MongoDB called `pymongo`):

```
basket = db['baskets'].find_one({'_id':basket_id})
fruits = db['fruits'].find({'_id':{'$in':basket[FRUIT_ARRAY]}})
```

Given that I have to do it for every basket in the collection, how can I make this procedure more efficient? I've heard about bulk operations but as far as I know, they are only about updates to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Since `baskets` and `fruits` are different collections, they are not related. Your two queries are fine to query across collection boundaries.

Comment: Could you expand your answer a little bit? Do you mean that my way of doing it is the most efficient one already?

Comment: The question is: Does it *work* and, if not, is there a *different* way. i can't see any.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, I knew that my code worked, I was just interested in finding a more efficient way to do it.